# JavaScript -Change CSS color for 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a way of briefly highlighting the text on named links - but only for a few seconds.

```
<a href="#faq1"onClick="document.getElementById('faq1').style.color='#f00'">
```

So on a list of FAQs - it jumps to the proper ID, changes the color to red for a few seconds as a visual cue to the end user (the answer is here).  but then returning to normal color and the interval is complete.

How do I make the above function to work for only a set period of time?

Comment: jQuery UI has a nice [Highlight effect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/) (See the drop-down on the demo page). This is actually used here on SO. I know adding jQuery is overkill for this but maybe you can work it into the rest of your site. Just a thought. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
function highlight(obj){
   var orig = obj.style.color;
   obj.style.color = '#f00';
   setTimeout(function(){
        obj.style.color = orig;
   }, 5000);
}
```

and in the html:

```
<a href="#faq1" onClick="highlight(document.getElementById('faq1'));">
```

this function will work for any object you pass to it :-)

here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/dG2ks/

Comment: love the solution and ability to pass the ID to the function.  works perfect for me since I have 20 FAQ questions.  allows me to not repeat code.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use window.setTimeout()

```
<a href="#faq1" onClick="highlight()">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function highlight() {
        var el = document.getElementById('faq1');
        var original = el.style.color;
        el.style.color='#f00';
        window.setTimeout(function() { el.style.color = original; }, 5000);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to change it back (by setting the same property to an empty string). Run it using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a id="faqLink" href="#faq1">FAQ Link</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('faqLink').onclick = function(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var srcEl = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var src = document.getElementById("faq1");
    var prevColor = src.style.color;
    src.style.color = '#f00';
    setTimeout(function(){
        src.style.color = prevColor;
    }, 5000); //5 seconds
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some JS:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     function changeColor(element, color){
        document.getElementById(element).style.color = color
        setTimeout(function(){ changeColor(element, '#000') }, 5000)
     }
</script>
```

Some HTML:

```
<a href="#faq1" onClick="changeColor('faq1', '#f00')">
```

Comment: that is assuming the orig color was `#000`

Comment: also this ends up in an infinite loop!

Answer (score 0):

This class and function will give a subtle flash to any element, drawing attention to it for a default of 3 sec when the function is called. (If you call the function for more than 3 sec it only flashes for 3 sec and is just slightly brighter after that) 
You may wish to remove the border to make it **more subtle**. 
Increase the alpha (a) in the border and background to make it **less subtle**.

```js
    const myElement = document.getElementById("myElement");

    function emphasise(element, time = 3) {
       element.classList.add("emphasise");
       setTimeout(function() {
         element.classList.remove("emphasise")
       }, time * 1000);
    }

    function myFunction() {
       myElement.innerText = 'kickable, throwable, punchable';
       emphasise(myElement, 4);
    }
```

```css
.emphasise {
  border: 2px dotted rgba(255, 122, 122, 0.5) !important; 
  border-radius: 3px;
  filter: brightness(115%);
  animation: highlight 3s;
}
@keyframes highlight {
  0% { background: hsla(50, 50%, 60%, 0.3)}
  11% { background: none }
  22% { background: hsla(50, 50%, 60%, 0.3) }
  33% { background: none }
  44% { background: hsla(50, 50%, 60%, 0.3)}
  56% { background: none }
  67% { background: hsla(50, 50%, 60%, 0.3) }
  78% { background: none }
  89% { background: hsla(50, 50%, 60%, 0.3) }
  100% { background: none }
}
    body{ background: beige }
    button{ padding: 10px,20px }
```

```html
<p>Hardware: <br>the <span id="myElement">physical</span> components of a computer
    </p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">
     click me
    </button>
```

see it in JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Andrei72/b8vwx4rp/43/)

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#faq1').css('color', '#f00');
setTimeout(function() {$('#faq1').css('color', '#000'); }, 5000);
```

Comment: why would u use jQuery for something so trivial, **and** the op is not using jquery that i can see

Comment: jQuery is the standard for browser independant DOM modification. As soon as you enter that area, why not do it properly?

Comment: why is it `standard`? its not standard for everyone. there are so many other DOM modifcation libraries