# JavaScript -Change CSS color for 5 seconds - How to add easing effect?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-easing

With the reference to this question:-

[JavaScript -Change CSS color for 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600351/javascript-change-css-color-for-5-seconds)

Working demo of the answer:-

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/dG2ks/

I need to know how i can add an easing effect to it, so that slowly and slowly color get 100% opaque and similarly get 100% transperent.

Comment: are you asking how to make it gradually change from black to red or from red to black?

Comment: Like the Highlight effect in Jquery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

```
function makeRGBStr(obj) {
    if (obj.a == null) return "rgb(" + obj.r + "," + obj.g + "," + obj.b + ")";
    else return "rgba(" + obj.r + "," + obj.g + "," + obj.b + "," + obj.a + ")";
}


window["highlight"] = function(obj, color) {
    var highlightColor = color || {
        "r": 255,
        "g": 0,
        "b": 0
    };


    var orig = obj.style.backgroundColor;
    var curAlpha = 1;
    obj.style.backgroundColor = makeRGBStr(highlightColor);
    setTimeout(function() {
        curAlpha -= 0.1;
        var newColor = highlightColor;
        newColor.a = curAlpha;
        obj.style.backgroundColor = makeRGBStr(newColor);

        if (curAlpha <= 0) {
            obj.style.backgroundColor = orig;
        }
        else {

            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
        }
    });
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dG2ks/32/

### Some examples

- Highlight if specific $_GET variable is present: 
  Code: http://jsfiddle.net/dG2ks/36/, see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/dG2ks/36/show/?someVar=there
- Highlight table cell: http://jsfiddle.net/dG2ks/38/
- Highlight all table cells with different colors: http://jsfiddle.net/dG2ks/40/

Comment: And if i only want to do this with background then i thing i just simply need to change `obj.style.color` to `obj.style.background-color`...

Comment: But then the text will also get affected by `style.opacity`. I will make an example...

Comment: Also i want this to be done automatically without click lets say when page reloads or when a variable passed through $_GET method

Comment: Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/dG2ks/32/. For the page reload, you could use `window.onload` and for $_GET you have to use `location.search`.

Comment: Another example with $_GET: http://jsfiddle.net/dG2ks/36/. You have to access http://jsfiddle.net/dG2ks/36/show/?someVar=9 in order to see it in action!

Comment: Hey can i do this thing for Table, as i have one `<td>` whose background i have changed to `#FFF` in CSS, now is it possible to trigger this thing for `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the jquery library, combined with jquery ui - if you don't use it already - and use the switchClass method.

All info here : http://jqueryui.com/demos/switchClass/

It will only take 5 lines to do what you want :

Place jquery en jquery ui in the head section of your page (2 lines of code).
These are the remotely hosted files, you can copy/paste the code 'as is'.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And then, at the end of the body, place a script that contains these three lines of code :

```
    $(".yourbutton".click(function() {
            switchClass('.currentclass','.redclass',500) 
            // transition from .currentclass to .redclass in 500 milliseconds
    });
```